# Openshift Spring boot docker image and Mongodb connection

Tags: mongodb, docker, spring-boot, openshift

I created a spring boot application (simple with database connection) and I would like to put it on a openshift. It's not a problem for me to generate docker image and put it into openshift, but I also want a mongodb database instance on openshift. I already created it on a openshift but know I have no idea how to connect to it from the spring boot application. I recently heard that I need to type a pod name as a connection string. Is that correct? How exactly should I connect to mongodb pod from the spring boot pod. Should I create some route between those two? I am new with playing around docker and openshift, so please try to give me as much info  as you can.

Comment: Consider go reading this free eBook on using OpenShift. It will step you through a lot of the basics. https://www.openshift.com/promotions/for-developers.html Also work through learning exercises at https://learn.openshift.com/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using your own OS3 vm?
I'm no expert on the matter, but on OS3 web console, once you create a database from templates already provided by OpenShift, OS3 shows a connection string at the end of the process.
I'm pretty sure OS3 creates a service for your db, the link looks like this:

```
mysql://servicename:3306/database
```